# Apache loading time in microseconds - difference between header and log

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, performance-monitoring

I recently followed [this guide](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/480-How-to-log-request-processing-times-with-Apache-) to obtain performance measurement of siteload on a web server.

> To log the time it takes for Apache to process a request add this to your apache configuration file:
>
> ```
> LogFormat "%h %D %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
> ```
>
> %D means you’ll see the time it took Apache to process the request in the access log. The time is measured in microseconds.
>
> To make it even easier to debug page load times, add this to your configuration file:
>
> ```
> Header set X-Request-Received: %t
> Header set X-Request-Processing-Time: %D
> ```
>
> Remember to enable mod_headers first by executing a2enmod headers.
>   Now you should see these headers in the response:
>
> ```
> X-Request-Received t=1286995673038485
> X-Request-Processing-Time D=251
> ```

I used exactly the code above (with header defined in .htaccess) but get for example "525151" in the log and "262" in the header for the same request. In general there seems to be orders of magnitude in difference between the numbers

```
192.0.2.1 525151 - - [21/Aug/2011:14:19:53 +0200] "GET /images/site/slide-1.png HTTP/1.1" 262 423285 "http://example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1"
```

vs.

```
X-Request-Processing-Time:D=262
X-Request-Received:t=1313929193502879
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It is sort of weird that where the status code should be (200) your example log line has '262' which I've never seen as a status code, and also the same number you said you were seeing in the headers.

Comment: "womble" changed the post, The original line was:


    [IP-ADDRESS] 525151 - - [21/Aug/2011:14:19:53 +0200] "GET /images/site/slide-1.png HTTP/1.1" 200 423285 "http://[DOMAIN]/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/13.0.782.112 Safari/535.1"

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify that your LogFormat name 'combined' matches what your CustomLog variable is using.  I tested this on OS X and aside from the minor difference you'd expect between reading the variable when writing back the headers and when logging (after sending all the data back to the client) they are very close:

```
/etc/apache2# grep LogF httpd.conf
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %t %D" common

/etc/apache2# grep CustomL httpd.conf
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/access_log" common


# wget -qqO /dev/null -S http://localhost/
...
  X-Request-Received: t=1314588821970347
  X-Request-Processing-Time: D=336

/private/var/log/apache2# tail access_log 
::1 - - [28/Aug/2011:20:33:41 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 44 [28/Aug/2011:20:33:41 -0700] 587
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet might be to choose a 'proper' name for your custom LogFormat, rather than reuse/change the `combined` log format.

All else aside (and as suggested by @polynomial), it seems as though there is a gap between the config you show, and the output you show.

If only to make troubleshooting less ambiguous (currently, you don't know if the default `combined` (`LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" combined`) or your version is being used).

So I would first do something like:

`LogFormat "%h %D %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" perf-combined`

And then use perf-combined where it is needed.

Looking at the fairly wide differences between Header %D and AccessLog %D values in @polynomial's example, I would also wonder whether the two are actually representing two different points in the request processing:

- since the header value of %D is lower in all examples on this page, it might show the time it took to form the response headers, but not necessarily body
- the AccessLog value of %D might be the time to send the full response.

That's a complete guess though.

Answer (score 1):

[This is a very old question, but worthy of a better answer for others who arrive here]

The HTTP header is necessarily generated before the content is delivered to the end user, so it excludes network delays.  The access_log entry on the other hand is written after the whole of the content is delivered to the end user, possibly over a slow network link, and it includes the time taken for that delivery.

Which figure is more useful to you depends on what you're trying to find out.  For your image URL, you're probably looking at end user performance, and network delays are probably most of the answer.

If you're debugging performance of dynamically generated content, you probably want to log the time excluding network delays.  LogFormat will let you log the content of a header with `%{X-Request-Processing-Time}i` - haven't tried it, but I expect that it'll work.